# cannot conenct to report builder 2.0

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, report-builder2.0

I work with sql server 2008

When I click the report builder button in report manager.a box shows up  "Cannot extract application .Authentification error"

Error details

```
* [23/04/2012 09:27:59] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (sous-type inconnu)
- Échec du téléchargement de http://admin-pc/ReportServer/ReportB...er.application.
- Source*: System.Deployment
- Trace de la pile*:
à System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
à System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
à System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
à System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
à System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
à System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
à System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
à System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
--- Exception interne ---
System.Net.WebException
- Le serveur distant a retourné une erreur*: (401) Non autorisé.
- Source*: System
- Trace de la pile*:
à System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
à System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
```

When I ran the application from the its directory

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQL2008\Reporting Services\ReportServer\ReportBuilder
```

It works fine but cannot connect to report server

Comment: I finally managed to solve the problem.the issue is thqt when the server is accessed through base authentifcation, click at once fail to launch.Either to set report server to connect via windows integrated security account or make access anonymly to report builder.For more informations http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the call is made from the user  configured to run SSRS. Does it have permission to do it? If the SSRS server is on you local computer, try setting your user to run it and then test again